# Type of ajax response data (Spidermonkey vs V8)

Tags: javascript, jquery, v8, spidermonkey

I have noticed this while performing an Ajax request to [Google Elevation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/) service:

```
jQuery.ajax({
   url: elevation_url,
   method: "get",
   async: false,
   data: {
      locations : elevation_points.join("|"), 
      sensor : false
   },
   success: function(data){
      console.log(typeof data);
   }
});
```

Firefox (version 19) outputs:

> String

while Chrome (version 26) outputs:

> object

Thus, I need to ensure, for example `my_function(data.status) ...` in Chrome, while doing `my_function(jQuery.parseJSON(data)) ...` in Firefox.

Any idea will be welcome, thak you!

**EDIT**

As suggested, adding `dataType: "json"` to ajax options solved the problem.

Comment: Have you tried adding `dataType:"json"`? If jQuery thinks the response is JSON it will parse it for you, but if it can't tell (perhaps because the server indicates the wrong MIME type) it might take it as plain text and return a string.

Comment: @nnnnnn +1, w/out specifying `dataType`, jQuery / the browser is left to determine the response type.

Comment: `async: "false"` is invalid, did you mean `async: true`? Also, the `typeof` operator is no function.

Comment: What `elevation_url` were you using? Did you expect [xml or json](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/#OutputFormats) data? What MIME type was returned?

Comment: Sorry, meant `async: false`. Edited `typeof` as operator, not function.